# Oracle get the data that related to the previous day

Tags: sql, oracle

Table PJASSIGN

| PPRJECT | LONINUSER | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MSFT | Ken | 01/12/2022 |
| MSFT | Ken | 01/13/2022 |
| MSFT | John | 01/20/2022 |
| MSFT | John | 01/25/2022 |
| GOOGLE | Gary | 03/13/2022 |
| GOOGLE | Gary | 03/14/2022 |
| GOOGLE | Gary | 03/15/2022 |
| GOOGLE | May | 03/16/2022 |
| TSLA | Juno | 05/18/2022 |
| TSLA | Juno | 05/20/2022 |
| TSLA | Juno | 05/22/2022 |
| TSLA | Juno | 05/24/2022 |

TABLE USERINFO

| USER_PJ_ID | LONINUSER | PJASSIGN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Ken | MSFT |
| 002 | Jay | APPL |
| 003 | John | MSFT |
| 004 | Mary | DELL |
| 005 | Gary | GOOGLE |
| 007 | Juno | TSLA |
| 009 | May | GOOGLE |

Only extract the data(LOGINUSER) that assign to the a project and working on it continues with more than two days. And do not show the data(LOGINUSER) that haven't assign the related project in the PJASSIGN table.
How can I get the expected result like below with the use of (sysday-1)?

Expected result

| LOGINUSER |
| --- |
| Ken |
| Gary |

How can I develop it to fit in the requirement?

```
Select LOGINUSER
From PJASSIGN
where (sysdate- 1,'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS' )
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why does the output include `Ken`? He has not been assigned to a project for more than 2 days? (He was only assigned to the project for exactly 2 days).

Comment: How does `SYSDATE` come into play here? It doesn't look like the task has anything to do with the current date. Or does it and I don't see it? What is `where (sysdate- 1,'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS' )` supposed to mean? It doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: Table `userinfo` doesn't provide any additional information to be used in the query. Why it is here? And `date` column in it looks corrupted.

Comment: @MT0 I am sorry that I ask the question incorrect. What I means is 2 days or more. Thanks.

Comment: @astentx I just change it to the right column, sry for the typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Oracle 12, use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row processing:

```sql
SELECT project,
       loninuser
FROM   PJAssign
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY project, loninuser
  ORDER     BY "DATE"
  PATTERN (first_day consecutive_days{2,})
  DEFINE
    consecutive_days AS PREV("DATE") + INTERVAL '1' DAY = "DATE"
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PJAssign (PROJECT, LONINUSER, "DATE") AS
SELECT 'MSFT',   'Ken',  DATE '2022-01-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MSFT',   'Ken',  DATE '2022-01-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MSFT',   'John', DATE '2022-01-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MSFT',   'John', DATE '2022-01-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'GOOGLE', 'Gary', DATE '2022-03-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'GOOGLE', 'Gary', DATE '2022-03-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'GOOGLE', 'Gary', DATE '2022-03-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'GOOGLE', 'May',  DATE '2022-03-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'TSLA',   'Juno', DATE '2022-05-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'TSLA',   'Juno', DATE '2022-05-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'TSLA',   'Juno', DATE '2022-05-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'TSLA',   'Juno', DATE '2022-05-24' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PROJECT | LONINUSER |
> | --- | --- |
> | GOOGLE | Gary |

*Note: Ken only worked on a project for exactly 2 days, not more than 2 days.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8605117e0dd1d97d249d28c5cb1bb84b)*

Comment: If you want "two-or-more days" then use `PATTERN (first_day consecutive_days+)`

Answer (score 0):

what about :

select distinct LOGINUSER from PJASSIGN where trunc(date) = trunc(sysdate -1 );

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need a LAG function to get your desired result -

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOGINUSER
  FROM (SELECT LONINUSER, DATE - LAG(DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY LONINUSER ORDER BY DATE) prev_date
          FROM PJASSIGN)
 WHERE prev_date = 1;
```

And as MT0 suggests, this will give you users who works on the proects for 2 days or more. If you need users more than 2 days, You need another logic.